# How to change disclosure style when user enters in edit mode of a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView that in 'normal' mode, show a UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator meaning if the user taps the row, another list is showed, like HIG says:

> "**Disclosure indicator**. When this
>   element is present, users know they
>   can tap anywhere in the row to see the
>   next level in the hierarchy or the
>   choices associated with the list item.
>   Use a disclosure indicator in a row
>   when selecting the row results in the
>   display of another list. ***Don’t use a
>   disclosure indicator to reveal
>   detailed information about the list
>   item; instead, use a detail disclosure
>   button for this purpose.***"

When the user tap the edit button in the top bar of the UITableView, I think I have to change the disclosure because if the user tap it, a view for changing the information of the current row is showed (see the bold line above), again, like HIG says:

> "**Detail disclosure button**. Users tap
>   this element to see detailed
>   information about the list item. (Note
>   that you can use this element in views
>   other than table views, to reveal
>   additional details about something;
>   see “Detail Disclosure Buttons” for
>   more information.)
>
> In a table view, use a detail
>   disclosure button in a row to display
>   details about the list item. Note that
>   the detail disclosure button, unlike
>   the disclosure indicator, can perform
>   an action that is separate from the
>   selection of the row. For example, in
>   Phone Favorites, tapping the row
>   initiates a call to the contact;
>   tapping the detail disclosure button
>   in the row reveals more information
>   about the contact."

Have I miss understood the HIG, or I really do have to change the disclosure style in edit mode of UITableView? If yes, how I can intercept the edit mode when the user taps the Edit button?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you do not need to manually change the disclosure indicator as the user switches in and out of edit mode. You can control what is displayed in edit mode by setting the "editingAccessoryType" property for the table cell. You would usually set that up in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method along with the "accessoryType" property which sets the disclosure indicator for the normal (non-editing) state.

From the table view programming guide:

- accessoryType and accessoryView—Allows you to set one of the standard accessory views (disclosure indicator or detail disclosure control) or a custom accessory view for a cell in normal (non-editing) mode. For a custom view, you may provide any UIView object, such as a slider, a switch, or a custom view.
- editingAccessoryType and editingAccessoryView—Allows you to set one of the standard accessory views (disclosure indicator or detail disclosure control) or a custom accessory view for a cell in editing mode. For a custom view, you may provide any UIView object, such as a slider, a switch, or a custom view. (These properties were introduced in iPhone OS 3.0.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Kharrison. Works very well for me.